# PHP Update Script not working, ID not pushing when it should be.

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that seems to not work, it it meant to update an SQL database. The code looks fine, but it seems to me that when I submit the ID in where the data is meant to be entered into doesn't work.

I can't seem to find the cause.  Can anyone here help me?

The script is below.

When I use the error check code, the only thing I get out of it is this:

> Query is : UPDATE ncmr SET ab = 'Matt Ridge', date = '2012-01-09',
>   part = 'K17212191', rev = '01' , partdesc = '' , ncmrqty = '2' , comp
>   = 'Nexx Systems Inc.' , ncmrid = '1243' , rma = 'Empty' , jno = 'Empty' , fdt = 'none' , cof = 'none' , fab1 = 'Andy Kahl' , fab2 =
>   '--None--' , fab3 = '--None--' , non = '' , dis = '' , comm = '' ,
>   caad = '' , po = 'Empty' , pod = '1969-12-31' , dri = '1969-12-31'
>   WHERE id = ''

There are no errors, but I notice that the ID is not showing upon posting. Is there a reason why this is happening?

I will post a link if required.

```
<?php
require_once('connectvars.php');
echo '<div id="postwrap">'
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>PDI NCMR - Edit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/postie.css" />
</head>
<body>
   <div id="logo">
    <img src="../images/PDI_Logo_2.1.gif" alt="PDI Logo" />
</div>

<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// Connect to the database
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

// Enter data into the database
    $ab = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['ab']));
    $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(date('Y-m-d',strtotime ($_POST['date']))));
    $part = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['part']));
    $rev = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['rev']));
    $partdesc = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['partdesc']));
    $ncmrqty = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['ncmrqty']));
    $comp = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['comp']));
    $ncmrid = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['ncmrid']));
    $rma = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['rma']));
    $jno = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['jno']));
    $fdt = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['fdt']));
    $cof = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['cof']));
    $fab1= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['fab1']));
    $fab2= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['fab2']));
    $fab3= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['fab3']));
    $non= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['non']));
    $dis= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['dis']));
    $comm= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['comm']));
    $caad= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['caad']));
    $po= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['po']));
    $pod = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['pod']))));
    $dri = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['dri']))));

    $query = "UPDATE ncmr SET ab = '$ab', date = '$date', part = '$part', rev = '$rev' , partdesc = '$partdesc' , ncmrqty = '$ncmrqty' , comp = '$comp' , ncmrid = '$ncmrid' , rma = '$rma' , jno = '$jno' , fdt = '$fdt' , cof = '$cof' , fab1 = '$fab1' , fab2 = '$fab2' , fab3 = '$fab3' , non = '$non' , dis = '$dis' , comm = '$comm' , caad = '$caad' , po = '$po' , pod = '$pod' , dri = '$dri'  WHERE id = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'";

 // echo your raw query and look for obvious errors
     echo "Query is : " . $query . "<br />";

      // and at least use a basic mechanism to trap possibles errors
       mysqli_query($dbc, $query)  or die('Query Error : ' . mysqli_error($dbc));

            // Clear the form data
    $ab = "";
    $date = "";
    $part = "";
    $rev = "";
    $partdesc = "";
    $ncmrqty = "";
    $comp = "";
    $ncmrid = "";
    $rma = "";
    $jno = "";
    $fdt = "";
    $cof = "";
    $fab1= "";
    $fab2= "";
    $fab3= "";
    $non= "";
    $dis= "";
    $comm= "";
    $caad= "";
    $po= "";
    $pod = "";
    $dri = "";

// Confirm success with the user
        echo '<p>If you wish to edit more NCMRs, please <a href="list.php">go to the admin page!</a></p>';

            mysqli_close($dbc);
            }

  else {    

// Connect to the database
  $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
// Grab the profile data from the database
  if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ncmr WHERE id = '$id'";
  }
  else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ncmr WHERE id = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'";
  }
  $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

  if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) { 
// The user row was found so display the user data
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
    echo'<div id="title"><h3 id="NCMR2">Non-Conforming Materials Report (NCMR:&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $row['rma'] . ')</h3></div>';
echo "<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>";
    echo '<fieldset>';

        echo '<div id="box1">';
            if (empty($row['ab'])) $row['ab'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['date'])) $row['date'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['part'])) $row['part'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['rev'])) $row['rev'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['partdesc'])) $row['partdesc'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['ncmrqty'])) $row['ncmrqty'] = "Empty";
            echo '<div id="ab"><span class="b">Added By:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="ab" value="' . $row['ab'] . '" /></div>';
            echo '<div id="date"><span class="b">Date Filed:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="date" value="' . $row['date'] . '" /></div>';
            echo '<div id="part"><span class="b">Part Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="part" value="' . $row['part'] . '" /></div>';
            echo '<div id="rev"><span class="b">Part Revision:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="rev" value="' . $row['rev'] . '" /></div>';
            echo '<div id="partdesc"><span class="b">Part Description:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="22">' . $row['partdesc'] . '</textarea></div>';
            echo '<div id="ncmrqty"><span class="b">NCMR Qty:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="ncmrqty" value="' . $row['ncmrqty'] . '" /></div>';
        echo '</div>';

//Company, Customer NCMR, Internal RMA, and Job Number
        echo '<div id="box2">';
            if (empty($row['comp'])) $row['comp'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['ncmrid'])) $row['ncmrid'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['rma'])) $row['rma'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['jno'])) $row['jno'] = "Empty";
                echo '<div id="comp"><span class="b">Company:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="comp" value="' . $row['comp'] . '" /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="ncmrid"><span class="b">Customer NCMR ID:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="ncmrid" value="' . $row['ncmrid'] . '" /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="rma"><span class="b">Internal RMA #:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="rma" value="' . $row['rma'] . '" /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="jno"><span class="b">Job #:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="jno" value="' . $row['jno'] . '" /></div>';
        echo '</div>';

//Type of Failure and Class of Failure
        echo '<div id="box3">';
            echo '<h2>Failure</h2>';
                echo '<div id="cof"><span class="b">Class of Failure:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="cof"  size="15" value="' . $row['cof'] . '" /></div>';
                echo '<div id="fdt"><span class="b">Failure Due To:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="fdt"  size="15" value="' . $row['fdt'] . '" /></div>';

            echo '</div>';

//Fabricators
        echo '<div id="box4">';
            echo '<h2>Fabricators</h2>';
if ($row['fab1']="--None--")
{
    echo'<div id="fab1">';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    $mysqli->select_db('user');
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
    echo "<SELECT name='fab1'>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row['user']}'>{$row['user']}</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo '</div>';
}
else
{
    echo'<div id="fab1">';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    $mysqli->select_db('user');
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
    echo "<SELECT name='fab1'>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row['user']}'>{$row['user']}</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo '</div>';
}


if ($row['fab2']="--None--")
{
    echo'<div id="fab2">';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    $mysqli->select_db('user');
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
    echo "<SELECT name='fab2'>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row['user']}'>{$row['user']}</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo '</div>';
}
else
{
    echo '<div id="fab2"><span class="b"></span><input type="text" name="fab1"  size="20" value="' . $row['fab1'] . '" /></div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
if ($row['fab3']="--None--")
{
    echo'<div id="fab3">';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    $mysqli->select_db('user');
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
    echo "<SELECT name='fab3'>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row['user']}'>{$row['user']}</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo '</div>';
}
else
{
    echo '<div id="fab3"><span class="b"></span><input type="text" name="fab1"  size="20" value="' . $row['fab1'] . '" /></div>';
    echo '</div>';
}       echo '</div>';

//Nonconformity, Disposition, Comments and Comments & Additional Details
        echo '<div id="box5">';
            if (empty($row['non'])) $row['non'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['dis'])) $row['dis'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['comm'])) $row['comm'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['caad'])) $row['caad'] = "Empty";

            echo '<div id="non"><span class="b">Nonconformity:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="105">' . $row['non'] . '</textarea></div>';
            echo '<div id="dis"><span class="b">Disposition:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="105">' . $row['dis'] . '</textarea></div>';
            echo '<div id="comm"><span class="b">Comments:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="105">' . $row['comm'] . '</textarea></div>';
            echo '<div id="caad"><span class="b">Comments and/or Additional Details:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="105">' . $row['caad'] . '</textarea></div>';

                echo '<div id="podr">';
                        if (empty($row['po'])) $row['po'] ="Empty";
                        if (empty($row['pod'])) $row['pod'] ="Empty";
                        if (empty($row['dir'])) $row['dri'] ="Empty";

                    echo '<div id="po"><span class="b">PO:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="po"  size="7" value="' . $row['po'] . '" /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="pod"><span class="b">PO Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="pod"  size="7" value="' . $row['pod'] . '" /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="dri"><span class="b">Date Received:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="dri"  size="7" value="' . $row['dri'] . '" /></div>';
                echo '</div>';
            echo '<div id="button2"><input type="submit" value="Submit Edits" name="submit" /></div>';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</fieldset>';
echo '</form>';
        }
    }

echo '</div>';

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You do not escape `$_GET['id']` => SQL injection!

Comment: please reduce your PHP script only to the update part or change your question to: *My page is not working when it should be.* - which isn't a question at all (as it's now not a question).

Comment: By the way, I think there's a SQL vulnerability at `...WHERE id = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'"`. I think you should escape ID too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using $_GET to retrieve the id but $_POST for everything else. Try changing it to $_POST...and there will be a host of warnings from everyone on SO about why this is dangerous. Look up SQL injection on google.

Comment: @Vincent_Radhanie So I should escape the ID as well? Thanks for telling me, I am still learning, I didn't think about doing that because once it is entered I figured it would be safe, but of course I'm not thinking like a hacker any more. So if I escape the ID, and put this to post, this should show up?

Comment: That's right. Once data is coming from the client you should never trust it. Even if it is hidden on a form. Remember that someone can fake the entire request that they send to your server, they do not have to submit your form.

Comment: Ok, I've entered the  $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['id'])); into the code now, when I do what you suggested the code still does not work, is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in form action instead of $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] - PHP_SELF won't include query string (and your id).

Also, when there is no id provided in GET you're using

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ncmr WHERE id = '$id'";
```

but there is no $id defined anywhere else in the script.

Comment: Ok, I have  $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['id']));
 in the script now, and have done what you suggested, and it still is not working correctly.